# Display records on map from SQL Statement across a relate

Tags: sql, arcgis-10.5, relates

I'm using ArcMap and I have a One-to-Many relate between two tables, one table contains polygons, and the other has additional data. Multiple records in the additional data table relate to a single record in the polygon table. The tables contain historical information.

What I want to do is use a SQL statement on the additional information table to select only buildings dating to the 1800s, and use my relate to have only these buildings shown on the map.

I've looked through all the information I can find, but there doesn't seem to be an answer. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A Definition Query (found in the layer properties) can limit the displayed items to just a SQL selection, however I don't know if this works across a relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the best way for me to do this would be to use a Query Table, and run Display Query on that table.